# Update Jersey Jackson's Mapper config at runtime

Tags: java, json, serialization, jersey, jackson

I have a client application that I am using to consume some API and update it. I am using Jersey 2.25.1 with Jersey Jackson and no custom connectors, just the basic setup.

I have a POJO that I am serializing using Jackson and Jersey, but I need this POJO to be serialized in two ways, first is to include all null values while serializing them, and second is to ignore and remove null fields.

This is how the API works so the API cannot be changed (it's not my API), so I am asking can I update the Jersey Jackson Mapper at runtime?

What I am looking for is something like:

```
 Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
            .register(JacksonFeature.class)
            .build();
 client.getJacksonObjectMapper().setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`ContextResolver`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ContextResolver.html), and configure the `ObjectMapper` there. The Jackson provider will call the context resolver to get the `ObjectMapper`

```
class JacksonResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public JacksonResolver() {
        // configure mapper
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper resolve(Class<?> cls) {
        return this.mapper;
    }
}

Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
        .register(JacksonFeature.class)
        .register(new JacksonResolver())
        .build();
```

Comment: can this be done after the client is created? I mean conditionally at runtime?

Comment: No. The best you're going to get is per model class. The class to be serialized is passed to the `getContext` method, and you can conditionally decide which mapper to use there, but that's really it. Other than that, the mapper isn't really supposed to be configured on a conditional basis like that, as its configuration is not thread-safe. You might just need to create different clients for different scenarios.

Comment: yeah seems like I will need to create another client then @peeskillet